# Delete in C++ linked list results in an infinite loop

Tags: c++, list, linked-list, destructor

### Edit

This is correct implementation of the List. Thank you guys especially Agent_L who helped me privately.

**CORRECT LINKED LIST IMPLEMENTATION**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include<iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class Node{
 friend class List;
public:
    Node(Node* next, int wrt){
        this->next = next;
        this->wrt = wrt;
    }

    Node(const Node& obiekt){
        this->wrt = obiekt.wrt;
        this->next = obiekt.next;
    }
     //NIE MA DESTRUKTORA BO NIE ALOKUJE ZADNYCH DANYCH !!!

    void show(){
        cout<<this->wrt<<endl;
    }




 private:
    Node* next;
    int wrt;

};


class List{

public:
List(int wrt){
    this->root = new Node(NULL, wrt);
}


    List(const List& list)
{
    // jesli pusty kopiujemy
    if (list.root == NULL)
    {
        this->root = NULL;
        return;
    }

    //tworzenie nowego korzenia
    this->root = new Node(NULL, list.root->wrt);

    Node* list_currentNode = list.root;
    Node* this_currentNode = this->root;
    while (list_currentNode->next != NULL)
    {
        // tworzenie nastepnika
        Node* newNode = new Node(NULL, list_currentNode->next->wrt);
        this_currentNode->next = newNode;
        this_currentNode = this_currentNode->next;
        list_currentNode = list_currentNode->next;
    }
}


void add(int wrt){
    Node* node = new Node(NULL, wrt);
    Node* el = this->root;
    while(el->next != NULL){
        //el->show();
        el = el->next;
    }
    el->next = node;
}

void remove(int index){
    Node* el = this->root;
    if(index == 0){
       this->root = el->next;
       delete el;
    }
   else{
    int i  = 0;
    while(el != NULL && i < index - 1){

        el = el->next;
        i++;
    }
     if(el!=NULL){
        Node* toRem = el->next;
        Node* newNext = toRem->next;
        el->next = newNext;
       delete toRem;
    }
}
}

void show(){
    Node* el = this->root;
    while(el != NULL){
        el->show();
        el = el->next;
    }
}

~List(){
    Node* currentNode = this->root;
    while (currentNode != NULL)
    {
        Node* nextNode = currentNode->next;
        delete currentNode;
        currentNode = nextNode;
    }
}


private:
    Node* root;

};

int main(){
    List* l = new List(11);
    l->add(22); l->add(33);
    l->show();
    cout<<endl;
    List* lala = new List(*l);
    lala->show();
    cout<<endl;
    lala->add(44);
    cout<<"lala before remove"<<endl;
    lala->show();
    lala->remove(1);
    cout<<"l before delete"<<endl;
    l->show();
    cout<<"lala before delete"<<endl;
    lala->show();
    delete l;
  /*  cout<<"l after delete   "<<endl;
    l->show(); */
    cout<<"lala after delete"<<endl;
    lala->show();
    return 0;
   }
```

---

I've implemented List and there is a problem. I've destructor in List which doesn't work as it should: please look at main and see "l after delete" it does print l list backwards.

The bigger problem is remove method without delelete inside it works as it should but when I try to uncomment delete el/delete to Rem I get into infinite loop.

Why these lines especially 87 (forget 100) cause the program crashes when I call l->remove(0)?

http://wklej.org/id/761056/ Lines 87 and 100

**remove method and List destructor are important**

```
void remove(int index){
    Node* el = this->root;
    if(index == 0){
       this->root = el->next;
    //   delete el;
    }
   else{
    int i  = 0;
    while(el != NULL && i < index - 1){

        el = el->next;
        i++;
    }
     if(el!=NULL){
        Node* toRem = el->next;
        Node* newNext = toRem->next;
        el->next = newNext;
       // delete toRem;
    }
}
}
```

---

```
 ~List(){
    Node* currentNode = this->root;
    while (currentNode != NULL)
    {
        Node* nextNode = currentNode->next;
        delete currentNode;
        currentNode = nextNode;
    }
}
```

---

Whole code

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include<iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class Node{
 friend class List;
public:
    Node(Node* next, int wrt){
        this->next = next;
        this->wrt = wrt;
    }

    Node(const Node& obiekt){
        this->wrt = obiekt.wrt;
        this->next = obiekt.next;
    }
     //NIE MA DESTRUKTORA BO NIE ALOKUJE ZADNYCH DANYCH !!!

    void show(){
        cout<<this->wrt<<endl;
    }




 private:
    Node* next;
    int wrt;

};


class List{

public:
List(int wrt){
    this->root = new Node(NULL, wrt);
}


    List(const List& list)
{
    // jesli pusty kopiujemy
    if (list.root == NULL)
    {
        this->root = NULL;
        return;
    }

    //tworzenie nowego korzenia
    this->root = new Node(NULL, list.root->wrt);

    Node* list_currentNode = list.root;
    Node* this_currentNode = this->root;
    while (list_currentNode->next != NULL)
    {
        // tworzenie nastepnika
        Node* newNode = new Node(NULL, list_currentNode->next->wrt);
        this_currentNode->next = newNode;
        this_currentNode = this_currentNode->next;
        list_currentNode = list_currentNode->next;
    }
}


void add(int wrt){
    Node* node = new Node(NULL, wrt);
    Node* el = this->root;
    while(el->next != NULL){
        //el->show();
        el = el->next;
    }
    el->next = node;
}

void remove(int index){
    Node* el = this->root;
    if(index == 0){
       this->root = el->next;
    //   delete el;
    }
   else{
    int i  = 0;
    while(el != NULL && i < index - 1){

        el = el->next;
        i++;
    }
     if(el!=NULL){
        Node* toRem = el->next;
        Node* newNext = toRem->next;
        el->next = newNext;
       // delete toRem;
    }
}
}

void show(){
    Node* el = this->root;
    while(el != NULL){
        el->show();
        el = el->next;
    }
}

~List(){
    Node* currentNode = this->root;
    while (currentNode != NULL)
    {
        Node* nextNode = currentNode->next;
        delete currentNode;
        currentNode = nextNode;
    }
}


private:
    Node* root;

};

int main(){
    List* l = new List(10);
    l->add(12); l->add(13);
    l->show();
    cout<<endl;
    List* lala = new List(*l);
    lala->show();
    cout<<endl;
    lala->add(4);
    cout<<"lala before remove"<<endl;
    lala->show();
    lala->remove(0);
    cout<<"l before delete"<<endl;
    l->show();
    cout<<"lala before delete"<<endl;
    lala->show();
    delete l;
    cout<<"l after"<<endl;
    l->show();
    cout<<"lala after delete"<<endl;
    lala->show();
    return 0;
   }
```

Comment: The code is too long. http://sscce.org/

Comment: Asking strangers to spot errors in your code by inspection is not productive.  You should identify (or at least isolate) the problem by using a debugger or print statements, and then come back with a more specific question (once you've narrowed it down to a 10-line [test-case](http://sscce.org)).

Comment: Also, I'd rephrase the question. I doubt that delete in C++ is broken, you're probably doing it wrong. If it was broken, we had a hell of a problem in the it-world.

Comment: Your code does not compile. Specifically the open parenthesis on this line (line 55) is not matched. `while (list_currentNode->// jesli pusty kopiujemynext)`

Comment: Code has been corrected 5 mins ago, I copied this one and it works.

Comment: just a comment, using std:list would be very appropriate here

Comment: I have corrected these not compiling code (it was compiling on my machine so i didn't notice)

Comment: `delete` in C++ *does* work. Just FYI

Comment: In C++ you would use `std::list` instead of your own attempt (in particular as you don't seem to implement any functionality that `std::list` doesn't have)

Comment: What actually is the question? "Delete in C++ doesn't work" is not a question. Perhaps you can ask a question.

Comment: Yes but I'd like to learn c++ i do some programming in java, but c++ is new for me(I used itg long time ago) and I want to learn how to delete these...

Comment: Your code crashes: http://codepad.org/c7k3KbA9

Comment: http://wklej.org/id/761080/ I use gcc and i ran it just right now

Comment: did you run through your code with a debugger line by line? If not, why did you ask us instead?

Comment: You can not access "l" after you delete it! That's illegal in C++!

Comment: Yes but should I get just nothing when I print it? Not the list printed backwards?

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not going to read all that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129787/147331)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Part**

Following three statements are causing infinite loop..

```
l->~List();
cout<<"l after"<<endl;
l->show();
```

Because your destructor `~List()` misses an important statement, which is...

```
this->root = NULL;
```

Which is the main reason for `infinite loop`. So here your full destructors goes..

```
 ~List()
 {
    Node* currentNode = this->root;
    while (currentNode != NULL)
    {
        Node* nextNode = currentNode->next;
        delete currentNode;
        currentNode = nextNode;
    }

    this->root = NULL;
}
```

**Second Part**

Now as you have update above three lines into following...

```
delete l;
cout<<"l after"<<endl;
l->show;              // We should never write this line in general practice..
```

And considering that you're using above `~List()` function. The reason for still program goes into an `infinite loop` is that `delete l` will de-allocate memory assigned to `l`. And you call `l->show()` (and as `l` is still pointing to an accessible linear address), so now `this->root` is pointing to some garbage location and thats why until it finds luckily `while(el != NULL)` condition NULL, it will stay in infinite-loop.

Comment: I added it and the effect is the same

        delete l;
        cout<<"l after delete   "<<endl;
        l->show();

originaly in the list l was: 11,22,33
show prints 33,22,11

Comment: @RobertKilar: My answer was based on `l->~List();` statement. But now you have changed it into `delete l;`. Previous statement will still preserve `l`'s members, but `delete l;` deallocates memory area allocated to `l`'s members too. How can you expect that `l->show();` should work?!!!! Thats why `this->root` is pointing to some garbled area and your program goes into infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

In a few places your code does not consider if items are NULL. E.g. What is root is NULL? Or what is toRem is NULL here? (Node* toRem = el->next; Node* newNext = toRem->next;)

There could be more problems but its a start...

Comment: But forgetting about this one if i call l->remove(0) the first part it won't also work even if it is not null. That's weird.

Comment: Side note, if this is homework ok, but otherwise why are you implementing a linked list? You should use a standard implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is correct implementation of the List. I think many people can find it useful. Thank you guys especcially Agent_L who helped me on comunicator.

**CORRECT LINKED LIST IMPLEMENTATION**

```
    #include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include<iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class Node{
 friend class List;
public:
    Node(Node* next, int wrt){
        this->next = next;
        this->wrt = wrt;
    }

    Node(const Node& obiekt){
        this->wrt = obiekt.wrt;
        this->next = obiekt.next;
    }
     //NIE MA DESTRUKTORA BO NIE ALOKUJE ZADNYCH DANYCH !!!

    void show(){
        cout<<this->wrt<<endl;
    }




 private:
    Node* next;
    int wrt;

};


class List{

public:
List(int wrt){
    this->root = new Node(NULL, wrt);
}


    List(const List& list)
{
    // jesli pusty kopiujemy
    if (list.root == NULL)
    {
        this->root = NULL;
        return;
    }

    //tworzenie nowego korzenia
    this->root = new Node(NULL, list.root->wrt);

    Node* list_currentNode = list.root;
    Node* this_currentNode = this->root;
    while (list_currentNode->next != NULL)
    {
        // tworzenie nastepnika
        Node* newNode = new Node(NULL, list_currentNode->next->wrt);
        this_currentNode->next = newNode;
        this_currentNode = this_currentNode->next;
        list_currentNode = list_currentNode->next;
    }
}


void add(int wrt){
    Node* node = new Node(NULL, wrt);
    Node* el = this->root;
    while(el->next != NULL){
        //el->show();
        el = el->next;
    }
    el->next = node;
}

void remove(int index){
    Node* el = this->root;
    if(index == 0){
       this->root = el->next;
       delete el;
    }
   else{
    int i  = 0;
    while(el != NULL && i < index - 1){

        el = el->next;
        i++;
    }
     if(el!=NULL){
        Node* toRem = el->next;
        Node* newNext = toRem->next;
        el->next = newNext;
       delete toRem;
    }
}
}

void show(){
    Node* el = this->root;
    while(el != NULL){
        el->show();
        el = el->next;
    }
}

~List(){
    Node* currentNode = this->root;
    while (currentNode != NULL)
    {
        Node* nextNode = currentNode->next;
        delete currentNode;
        currentNode = nextNode;
    }
}


private:
    Node* root;

};

int main(){
    List* l = new List(11);
    l->add(22); l->add(33);
    l->show();
    cout<<endl;
    List* lala = new List(*l);
    lala->show();
    cout<<endl;
    lala->add(44);
    cout<<"lala before remove"<<endl;
    lala->show();
    lala->remove(1);
    cout<<"l before delete"<<endl;
    l->show();
    cout<<"lala before delete"<<endl;
    lala->show();
    delete l;
  /*  cout<<"l after delete   "<<endl;
    l->show(); */
    cout<<"lala after delete"<<endl;
    lala->show();
    return 0;
   }
```